# How can I set the connection retry timer in the Ecto Postgrex driver

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

When my application starts, and the database hostname cannot be resolved, the Ecto/Postgrex driver now retries 20 times within the same second, and then Phoenix exits. Here's the error:

```
failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (odoodb:5432): non-existing domain - :nxdomain
```

I want to control the time between retries, and the amount of retries as well. How do I do that? Couldn't find anything in the docs.

BTW: running in docker, so DNS can suddenly start working.

Here are the software versions I use:

```
  {:phoenix, "~> 1.3.0-rc"},
  {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
  {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0"},
  {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
  {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.6"},
  {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
  {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
  {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
  {:distillery, "~> 1.0"},
  {:xain, "~> 0.6"},
  {:comeonin, "~> 3.0"},
  {:ueberauth_identity, "~> 0.2"},
  {:ueberauth_github, "~> 0.4"},
  {:ueberauth_google, "~> 0.5"},
  {:ueberauth_facebook, "~> 0.6"},
  {:bamboo, "~> 0.8"},
  {:timex, "~> 3.0"},
  {:scrivener_ecto, "~> 1.0"},
```

Here is the code that exits:

```
defmodule Backend.Application do
  use Application

  # See http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Application.html
  # for more information on OTP Applications
  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec

    # Define workers and child supervisors to be supervised
    children = [
      # Start the Ecto repository
      supervisor(Backend.Web.Repo, []),
      # Start the endpoint when the application starts
      supervisor(Backend.Web.Endpoint, []),
      # Start your own worker by calling: Backend.Worker.start_link(arg1, arg2, arg3)
      # worker(Backend.Worker, [arg1, arg2, arg3]),
    ]

    # See http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Supervisor.html
    # for other strategies and supported options
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Backend.Supervisor]
    res = Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
    IO.puts "######### run migrations..."
    Ecto.Migrator.run(Backend.Web.Repo, Path.join(["#{:code.priv_dir(:backend)}", "repo", "migrations"]), :up, all: true)
    IO.puts "######### migrations done..."
    res
  end
end
```

I think it's actually exiting in Migrator.run. Here's the error:

```
 ######### run migrations...
 08:31:22.774 [info] Application backend exited: exited in: Backend.Application.start(:normal, [])
     ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
         ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) connection not available because of disconnection
             (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:925: DBConnection.checkout/2
             (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:741: DBConnection.run/3
             (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:1132: DBConnection.run_meter/3
             (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:584: DBConnection.prepare_execute/4
             (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/postgres/connection.ex:93: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.Connection.execute/4
             (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:243: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.sql_call/6
             (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:193: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!/5
             (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/postgres.ex:86: anonymous fn/4 in Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.execute_ddl/3
             (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1755: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
             (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/postgres.ex:86: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.execute_ddl/3
             (ecto) lib/ecto/migrator.ex:43: Ecto.Migrator.migrated_versions/2
             (ecto) lib/ecto/migrator.ex:142: Ecto.Migrator.run/4
             (backend) lib/backend/application.ex:24: Backend.Application.start/2
             (kernel) application_master.erl:273: :application_master.start_it_old/4
```

So I think my question now becomes: how do I wait for a working connection, or how do I make migrator wait for it?

Also I'd still like to be able to make the driver wait longer between retries.

Comment: I just tried with a non-existent host and Phoenix is still trying to connect after a minute and 100s of attempts. The error message is the same as yours. Which version of Ecto and Phoenix are you on?

Comment: I added info to the question

Comment: One crude way would be to catch this specific error and retry after a sleep (https://gist.github.com/e5ea91b67617f5fb351036bc7a97d5bd) but there's probably a better solution where the code will wait until the database is connected.

Comment: The gist works, and helped me continue, but unfortunately is not the answer to the question as stated.